# create dblclick-to-select along with zoom in d3.js bubbles?

Tags: javascript, events, svg, zooming, d3.js

From the d3.js bubbles example I have added the zoom + pan functions. Now I want to allow users to select a bubble on desktops and touch-screens. The dblclick and touchstart seem to be consistent for this.

I know d3 provides a way to cancel an event from .zoom but then it is disabled and doesn't do anything.

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom)).on("dblclick", null);
```

Link: http://bl.ocks.org/4163494

What I have above sort of works but you will notice that a dblclick doesn't zoom at first but then it is revealed if you cause another zoom event. I am looking for the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix I left the

```
.on("zoom", redraw)
```

function where it was but moved the dblclick down to the circle, text, and tspan elements. From there they call a function that first stops propagation and then selects the circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnzS9/